# Data transfer and synchronization between two postgresql database with python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, data-transfer, data-synchronization

I want transfer and synchronize data between table_1 and table_2 from source database(postgresql) to target database(postgresql) with same table structure. I need this 3 logic:

1. in table_2 if record does not exist in table_1 then delete this record from table_2
2. in table_2 if any record different in table_1 then update only differenced records in table_2 not all records
3. in table_1 if any record does not exist table2 then insert this record to table2

   I wrote this logic in same database with SQL but I need this logic in python.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE table_1
   (
       id   INT,
       name VARCHAR(50)
   );

   INSERT INTO table_1
   VALUES (1, 'A'),
          (2, 'B'),
          (3, 'C'),
          (4, 'D'),
          (5, 'E'),
          (6, 'F');

   CREATE TABLE table_2 AS
   SELECT *
   FROM table_1;

   INSERT INTO table_1
   VALUES (7, 'Z');

   DELETE
   FROM table_1
   WHERE name = 'C';

   UPDATE table_1
   SET name = 'W'
   WHERE name = 'E';


   DELETE
   FROM table_2
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table_1
                     WHERE table_1.id = table_2.id);

   UPDATE table_2
   SET name = table_1.name
   FROM table_1
   WHERE table_2.id = table_1.id
     AND table_2.name != table_1.name;

   INSERT INTO table_2 (id, name)
   SELECT id, name
   FROM table_1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM table_2
                     WHERE table_2.id = table_1.id);
   ```

```
import psycopg2

# Connect to source database
source_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="source_host",
    database="source_db",
    user="source_user",
    password="source_password"
)

# Connect to target database
target_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host="target_host",
    database="target_db",
    user="target_user",
    password="target_password"
)

# Create a cursor for both connections
source_cursor = source_conn.cursor()
target_cursor = target_conn.cursor()

# Select data from table_1 in the source database
select_query = "SELECT * FROM table_1;"
source_cursor.execute(select_query)
source_data_rows = source_cursor.fetchall()

# Select data from table_2 in the target database
select_query = "SELECT * FROM table_2;"
target_cursor.execute(select_query)
target_data_rows = target_cursor.fetchall()

# Create a dictionary to store the source data
source_data = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in source_data_rows}

print("Source data:")
for row in source_data_rows:
    print(row)

print("Target data:")
for row in target_data_rows:
    print(row)

# Iterate over the target data to perform synchronization
deleted_count = 0
updated_count = 0
inserted_count = 0

for row in target_data_rows:
    target_id = row[0]
    target_data = row[1:]

    if target_id not in source_data:
        # Delete record from table_2 if it doesn't exist in table_1
        delete_query = "DELETE FROM table_2 WHERE id = %s;"
        target_cursor.execute(delete_query, (target_id,))
        deleted_count += 1
        print(f"Deleted record with id {target_id}")
    else:
        source_data_row = source_data[target_id]

        if target_data != source_data_row:
            # Update record in table_2 if it has different data in table_1
            update_query = "UPDATE table_2 SET column1 = %s, column2 = %s, ... WHERE id = %s;"
            target_cursor.execute(update_query, (*source_data_row, target_id))
            updated_count += 1
            print(f"Updated record with id {target_id}")

# Insert new records from table_1 into table_2
insert_values = [(id, *data) for id, data in source_data.items() if id not in target_data_rows]
if insert_values:
    insert_query = "INSERT INTO table_2 (id, column1, column2, ...) VALUES %s;"
    psycopg2.extras.execute_values(target_cursor, insert_query, insert_values)
    inserted_count += len(insert_values)
    print(f"Inserted {len(insert_values)} records")

# Commit the changes and close the connections
target_conn.commit()

source_cursor.close()
source_conn.close()

target_cursor.close()
target_conn.close()

# Print the synchronization results
print(f"{deleted_count} records deleted.")
print(f"{updated_count} records updated.")
print(f"{inserted_count} records inserted.")
```

Comment: Show us what Python code you have wrote so far!

Comment: Python code added. @KlausD.

Comment: Use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) to set up a foreign table in database 1 to the table in database 2 and then use the queries from your first example.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I can not use for security reason fdw, thanks

Comment: 1) How is that less secure then connecting to both the same database in the Python code? 2) Use the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) module and load the tables into temp sqlite database and do the queries on them.